# Uanble to click elements - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a top nav bar, but for some reason I can't click any of the buttons inside my website.

```
import '../css/TopBarStyle.css'
import Logo from './Logo'
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";


function TopNavBar() {
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className='logo-div'>
                <Logo />
            </div>
            <div className='navigation-buttons'>
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => {alert("Hello")}}>Home</button>
                <button>My Projects</button>
                <button>About me</button>
                <button>Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TopNavBar;
```

## Update (css file added)

**My css file:**

```
.container {
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navigation-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

button {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.315);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I can't see where is the problem with this. I'm using safari so I can't inspect my page to see the elements

Comment: Safari has devtools. See https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-developer-tools-in-the-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably `logo-div` is on top of `.navigation-buttons`, you can press Ctrl + Shift + C in chrome to see what you're clicking on

> remove `position: absolute` from `".navigation-buttons"` if you don't need it or add `z-index: 100` to it

Comment: try using chrome or firefox for development, they have nice debugging tools, you can also add this in css `*{outline: 1px solid red;}` applies 1 border to every element so you can see what space every element takes

Comment: I added z-index: 9999 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it is actually working (whenever I click the "Home" button, an alert box appears that says "Hello").

If it is not working for you, you may want to share the CSS file, so we all can check if there is a problem with styling (which can make the navbar behave differently).

**AFTER EDIT**

The main problem is that the buttons have a `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.315)` which is basically white (so you can't see them if the background of the page is white too). Note that `color:white` will make text white as well.

You might want to change them to `background-color: rgba(202, 227, 209)` for example and to `color:black`.
This way you'll have your navigation buttons with black text and light grey background.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import '../css/TopBarStyle.css'
import Logo from './Logo'
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";


function TopNavBar() {
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className='logo-div'>
                <Logo />
            </div>
            <div className='navigation-buttons'>
                <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  alert("button clicked");
                }}>Home</button>
                <button>My Projects</button>
                <button>About me</button>
                <button>Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TopNavBar;
```

You can avoid page reload by using **preventDefault()** function .

```
<button type="submit" onClick={(event) => {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  alert("button clicked");
}}>
Home </button>
```

Comment: Ohh ! Is the answer not relevant to you now ? Should I delete it ?